# Onde o JWT guarda os tokens?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express.js, jwt

Estou seguindo o seguinte tutorial para criar um sistema de autenticação usando Node.js e JWT: https://scotch.io/tutorials/authenticate-a-node-js-api-with-json-web-tokens

Seguindo os passos do tutorial, consigo verificar se o usuário está correto e criar o JWT. Porém, aparentemente, o token não está sendo guardado em lugar nenhum. Ao acessar a rota /teste, nada é retornado. Segue o código:

```
const express = require('express');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

const router = express.Router();

const Usuario = require('../models/Usuario');

router.get('/teste', (req, res) => {
  const token = req.body.token || req.query.token || req.headers['x-access-token'] || null;
  return res.json(token);
});

router.post('/login', (req, res) => {
  Usuario.findOne({ email: req.body.email, senha: req.body.senha }, (err, usuario) => {
    if (err) return res.json({ error: err });
    if (!usuario) return res.json({ error: 'Email e/ou senha incorretos!' });

    jwt.sign(usuario, 'secret', { expiresIn: 3600 }, (err, token) => {
      if (err) return res.json({ error: err });
      return res.json({ message: 'Logado com sucesso!', token: token });
    });
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Você está enviando o jwt como no seu request?

Comment: Não estou enviando JWT no request, pensei que o método sign fizesse isso automaticamente. Como posso passar esse token para frente via headers, então, Vinicius?

Comment: Você recebe o token na resposta do sign in,  vc tem q pegar esse token e armazenar em algum lugar. Se seu cliente for um browser pode.ser nos cookies por exemplo. Ai como adicionar o header vai depender do cliente que você está utilizando para fazer o request.

Comment: Entendi. No caso, gostaria de não usar cookies para isso, como posso fazer para ir passando esse token pelo header x-access-token?

Comment: No caso do postman vc deve adicionar um header x-access-token na configuração do request.

Answer (score 1):

O `token` não fica guardado. Em uma requisição tu vai precisar informar ele, normalmente por `headers`, mas pode ser por onde quiser.

O servidor receberá o `token` e vai validar com a **chave privada**. Assim, tu tens os dados validados do `token`.

Answer (score 1):

O [padrão JSON Web Token (JWT)](https://jwt.io/) apenas define um protocolo e formato de troca de tokens de acesso - armazenamento não é parte da especificação. Tradução do [artigo na Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_Web_Token):

> [...] é um padrão aberto baseado em JSON (RFC 7519) para criar tokens de acesso que afirmam um certo número de reivindicações. [...] Os tokens são projetados para serem compactos, seguros para URL e utilizáveis ​​especialmente no contexto de logon único de navegador da Web (SSO). As reivindicações JWT podem ser tipicamente usadas para passar identidade de usuários autenticados entre um provedor de identidade e um provedor de serviços, ou qualquer outro tipo de reivindicações conforme exigido por processos de negócios. Os tokens também podem ser autenticados e criptografados.

O armazenamento destes tokens deve então ser explicitamente implementado. Existem várias maneiras, e a escolha dependerá do seu modelo. Alguns exemplos aqui: [1](https://www.sitepoint.com/using-json-web-tokens-node-js/), [2](https://scotch.io/tutorials/authenticate-a-node-js-api-with-json-web-tokens), [3](https://stormpath.com/blog/nodejs-jwt-create-verify).

Answer (score 0):

Olá, basta passar no Header de sua requisição. Como está usando o nome 'x-access-token'.

Usando jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
   url : 'api/route',
   headers: {
        'x-access-token' : token
   });
```

Depois sua middleware de autenticação vai receber esse token e irá validar, para que consiga pegar o payload depois no método ;)

Answer (score 0):

Voce pode armazenar no LocalStorage, quando fizer a requisição AJAX no cliente.