# Qual a melhor maneira de realizar a autorização com JWT?

Tags: angularjs, jwt

Fiz essa pergunta anteriormente, porém acredito que não me expressei da forma correta. Então estou reformulando para tentar ser mais claro.

- Tenho várias API Rest, onde utilizo basic http, para evitar acesso direto.
- Front-end em AngularJS, desacoplado de todas API Rest. Onde este front acessa todas as APIs, enviando nos headers a autenticação (basic http). Esta funcionando tudo corretamente.
- Estou desenvolvendo outra API Rest, que terá a responsabilidade de autenticar os usuários da empresa e gerar tokens. Estou utilizando (io.jsonwebtoken), consigo gerar os tokens, com as permissões necessárias de cada usuário.
- No front-end, estou utilizando o (angular-jwt), fiz testes realizando login, armazenando o token no Local Storage, recuperando este token e pegando as informações do usuário que realizou o login, no logout consigo remover o token e funcionou corretamente.

**A estratégia que pensei em adotar é a seguinte:**

- Quando o usuário realizar o login com sucesso, vou gerar o token, armazenar no Local Storage e utilizando o (jwtHelper.decodeToken) do angular-jwt vou armazenar as informações deste usuário ($rootScope.usuarioAutenticado) por exemplo.
- Sempre que acontecer uma mudança de rota, eu utilizo o ($rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart'), e verifico se existe um token e se este token não expirou (jwtHelper.isTokenExpired).

**É a melhor prática para esta situação?**

Pensei dessa forma, pois não vou precisar enviar o token nas requisições (headers) das outras APIs Rest.

Comment: Votei para fechar. A pergunta parece querer uma opinião sobre o assunto. Creio que pelo que está sendo pedido na pergunta, poderia levar a inúmeras respostas. Entenda isso: A pergunta não está ruim, mas precisa ser adaptada.

Comment: Me da uma sugestão pelo menos, pois foi a melhor maneira que pensei em expor essa dúvida

Comment: Discordo das duas opiniões acima, a pergunta esta clara. Ele quer saber qual a melhor prática nesta determinada situação.

Comment: Pelo texto, parece pedir opinião sim, talvez editando a parte final, definindo melhor a duvida(sem pedir opiniao como melhor maneira, etc), a pergunta fique bacana pro site.

Comment: Retirei a parte final, onde parece que estou pedindo uma opinião. Acredito que se eu retirar a parte que explica a estratégia que estou pensando em adotar, a pergunta não vai ficar clara. mas se alguem tiver mais alguma opinião eu edito novamente, sem problemas. Quero que a pergunte fique clara, onde quero saber a melhor prática a ser adotada nesta situação.

Comment: Ficou melhor dessa forma @diegofm ?

Comment: @VanOliveira está claro que ele quer uma opinião. "É a melhor prática para esta situação?" é algo bem subjetivo. "Boas práticas" e "melhores prática" sempre acaba caindo nessa situação.

Comment: Relacionado: [O que é e pra que serve JWT](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/155013/o-que-%C3%A9-e-para-que-serve-jwt)

Comment: Obrigado @WallaceMaxters
Quando eu estava pesquisando eu vi essa postagem. Mas mesmo ainda ainda me deixou na dúvida, a abordagem que estou usando é correta? Pois o ambiente que tenho são várias API Rest (microserviços) com responsabilidades únicas, e tenho que controlar a autorização de cada usuário dos setores a cada serviço. Tem setores que tenho até 4 níveis de acesso, outros tenho apenas 2.

Comment: Até foi dessa postagem @WallaceMaxters que tirei a ideia de gerar tokens que vão expirar depois de determinadas horas. Pois como não vou enviar o token nas requisições p/ as outras API Rest, quando acesso uma rota segura, eu verifico se existe um token no local storage e se ele não expirou. Mas o que eu não sei, é se esta abordagem é a correta a fazer.