# Qual é a diferença entre JWT e JWS?

Tags: json, jwt

Eu fiz uma pergunta a pouco tempo  no site a respeito do [JWT](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/155013/o-que-%C3%A9-e-para-que-serve-jwt/155045), que é usado para criar tokens de acesso através do JSON.

Tentei implementar JWT entre duas aplicações que usam versões diferentes de uma biblioteca que gera tokens JWT.

A saber a versão 0.4 e 0.5 dessa [biblioteca](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/wiki).

Eu estava vendo que estava sendo gerado um erro entre essas duas aplicações, sendo que a chave privada era a mesma e os claims também era normalmente reconhecidos. Porém percebi ao usar o [JWT.IO](https://jwt.io/) que um resultado do header  `type` eram diferentes.

Quando colocava determinado token (gerado pela versão 0.4 da biblioteca) aparecia isso na sessão *HEADER*:

```
{
  "alg": "HS256",
  "typ": "JWS"
}
```

Quando usei o token gerado pela versão 0.5 da biblioteca acima, apareceu esse *HEADER*:

```
{
  "typ": "JWT",
  "alg": "HS256"
}
```

Sendo assim, imagino que esse foi o motivo de eu não ter conseguido manter a comunicação via JWT entre as duas aplicações, uma vez que cada uma está implementando um `typ` diferente.

Eu tenho algumas dúvidas:

- Qual é a diferença entre JWS e JWT?
- O que seria esse `typ` em um Header de Token JWT?

Comment: Quem inventou esses nomes é ruim de marketing. Mesmo com a discussão anterior sobre JWT, eu continuo olhando pra essas siglas e pensando imediatamente em Java!

Comment: @bfavaretto kkkkk, é exatamente isso. O problema é que ainda teve duas respostas excluídas nas outras perguntas. Não que a outra esteja boa, mas ter mais de uma resposta pra mim gera mais segurança.

Answer (score 2):

JWT usa o JWS para sua assinatura, a partir da especificação:

O **JSON Web Token (JWT)** é um meio compacto, seguro para URL, de representar reivindicações a serem transferidas entre duas partes. As requisições em um JWT são codificadas como um objeto JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) que é usado como uma estrutura **JSON Web Signature (JWS)** ou como o texto claro de uma estrutura JSON Web Encryption (JWE), permitindo que as reivindicações sejam Digitalmente assinado ou MACed e / ou criptografado.

Entao, um JWT é uma estrutura JWS com um objeto JSON como a carga útil. Algumas chaves opcionais (ou reivindicações) foram definidas como iss, aud, exp etc.

Isso também significa que sua proteção de integridade não é apenas limitada a segredos compartilhados, mas criptografia de chave pública / privada também pode ser usado.

**"Typ"** (type) Parâmetro de header
O type (header) Parâmetro definido por [JWS] e [JWE] é usado por aplicativos JWT para declarar o tipo de mídia [IANA.MediaTypes] deste JWT