# Como usar o $.on em JavaScript puro: "$(...).on(evento, seletor, função)"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, seletores

É o seguinte, em [jQuery temos o `on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/), qualquer elemento `<a>` com a classe `test` e **sem** a classe `foo` irão disparar a função quando clicados, **mesmo que você crie o elemento depois** do evento já estar adicionado:

```js
$("#new").click(function () {
    $('<p><a class="test" href="#">Novo: (' + (new Date) + ')</a></p>').appendTo("#container");
});

$("#container").on("click", "a.test:not(.foo)", function () {
    console.log("Funcionou!");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="new">Adicionar novo</button><br>

<div id="container">
   <p><a href="#">Oi (não funciona)</a></p>
</div>
```

Note que no teste somente os elementos adicionados posteriormente funcionam, ou seja coisas como `document.querySelector().forEach` não irão funcionar, a não ser que use [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver), mas então isto ainda seria um **terceiro comportamento**.

No inicio eu pensei que o jQuery usava [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver), mas após alguns testes percebi que na verdade o evento realmente esta em `document` e `#foobar`, então como eu tenho costume de usar [Vanilla.js](http://vanilla-js.com) eu comecei a tentar recriar isto, para isto usei o [`Element.addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)+[`Event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target), ficou algo como:

```js
var container = document.getElementById("container");
var newBtn = document.getElementById("new");

on(container, "click", "a.test:not(.foo)", function () {
    console.log("achou:", this);
});

newBtn.onclick = function () {
    var n = document.createElement("p");

    n.innerHTML = '<a class="test" href="#">Novo: (' + (new Date) + ')</a>';

    container.appendChild(n);
};

function on(target, type, selector, callback)
{
    target.addEventListener(type, function (e)
    {
         var el = e.target,
             els = document.querySelectorAll(selector);

         for (var i = 0, j = els.length; i < els.length; i++) {
             if (els[i] === el) {
                 callback.call(el, e); //Passa o elemento como this e o event como primeiro argumento
                 break;
             }
         }
    });
}
```

```html
<button id="new">Adicionar novo</button><br>

<div id="container">
   <p><a href="#">Oi (não funciona)</a></p>
</div>
```

No entanto isto não me parece muito performático, a duvida é a seguinte:

- Existe alguma maneira de testar um elemento especifico com um *queryselector*?

Comment: No caso, você está tentando recriar o comportamento do `on` do jQuery com Vanilla?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss isso "jquery.on em JavaScript puro", claro que meu exemplo que funciona não esta perfeito, é mais um pseudo-código, mas vou ajusta-lo só pra terem noção

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, apaguei todo o restante, deixa pra lá. Havia um print provando que não lhe negativei. Não sei se é isso que quer desta vez, não vou postar como resposta, mas seria o que eu iria reformular, baseada na resposta do Sergio e na função de exemplo que você deu - https://jsfiddle.net/vco5ptwm/1/ - Desculpe por não ter entendido de primeira sua pergunta.

Comment: Não quero nada e seja lá quem for já removeu o downvote, entenda uma coisa @RenanCavalieri, eu não sou contra downvotes, desde que usados devidamente, veja esta situação do meu passado aonde recebi um downvote https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/155013/o-que-é-e-para-que-serve-jwt/155045#comment320258_155045, apesar de discordar do downvote naquele momento, dentro do entendimento do Kaio faz até sentido, tanto mesmo minha resposta tendo sofrido eu apoiei. O problema não foi o downvote e sim a motivação dele, então quero que quando receber um comentário como critica:

Comment: [Seja receptivo, paciente e sempre presuma boas intenções.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) Até mais um grande abraço ;)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Isto é delegação de eventos com elemento delegado associado a um seletor CSS mais complexo.

`$(document).on("click"` quer dizer que o auscultador de evento está amarrado ao `document`. Então já temos `document.addEventListener`.

Depois precisamos de tratar o `event.target` para saber que o evento foi foi nesse elemento, ou num descendente. Para isso precisamos de verificar os seletores. Podemos usar o [`.matches()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/matches) que verifica se um dado elemento acerta com um dado seletor de CSS, e associar ao [`:not()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/:not) que já é suportado por browsers modernos para garantir que a *class* errada não é aceite.

Podíamos fazer isso assim:

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  var correto = e.target.matches('a.test:not(.foo)');
  // ...
});
```

#### Exemplo com testes:

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  var correto = e.target.matches('a.test:not(.foo)');
  
  // o resto é só para o exemplo
  var seletor = [e.target.tagName.toLowerCase(), ...e.target.className.split(' ')].filter(Boolean).join('.');
  console.log(seletor, '|', correto ? 'encontrado!' : 'falhou...', e.target.innerHTML);

});
```

```css
a {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #005;
  width: 10px;
}

a:hover {
  color: #aaf;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<a class="qq-coisa">A</a>
<a class="test foo">B</a>
<a class="foo">C</a>
<a class="test">D</a>
```

Comment: O matches não pode receber o `:not`, tem algum motivo para separar? A ideia seria poder usar qualquer seletor.  Obrigado desde já parece ser o melhor caminho mesmo.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento pode pode! Eu é que pensava que estava menos bem suportado, o IE 9 aceita. Vou editar.

Comment: Vou ler bem a respeito e logo volto com o ✔  ;) +1 esta garantido

Comment: Obrigado mesmo e parabéns! Funcionou exatamente como esperado, deixei uma resposta com um polyfill :) Até mais

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento estava a ler a tua resposta `+1`!

Answer (score 8):

Um adendo a [resposta do Sérgio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/210760/3635) é a questão dos prefixos, o `Element.matches` não é suportando por alguns navegadores mais antigos, ou tinham um nome diferente (como `matchesSelector`).

### Navegadores e Element.matches

Até o Chrome 33, Opera 15 e Safari 7.0 usavam o prefixo:

```
.webkitMatchesSelector
```

Firefox até a versão 33 usava:

```
.mozMatchesSelector
```

Internet Explorer usa desde a versão 9 (nenhuma versão usa o `matches`):

```
.msMatchesSelector
```

Opera Presto a partir do 11.5 usava:

```
.oMatchesSelector
```

### Alternativa ao Element.matches e aos prefixados

Navegadores mais antigos podem suportar `querySelectorAll`, mas talvez não tenham suporte ao `matches` e aos prefixados como `webkitMatchesSelector`, para isto o site da [*MDN*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches) encontrei um exemplo que usa `Element.document` ou `Element.ownerDocument`, uma versão simples para testar seria isto:

```
function elementMatchs(el, selector) {
    var i = matches.length,
        matches = (el.document || el.ownerDocument).querySelectorAll(selector);

    while (--i >= 0 && matches.item(i) !== el) {}
    return i > -1;
}
```

### Polyfill Element.matchs

O site da [*MDN*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches) também tem um exemplo interessante de para termos uma compatibilidade maior com navegadores antigos e novos:

```
if (!Element.prototype.matches) {
    Element.prototype.matches = 
    Element.prototype.matchesSelector || 
    Element.prototype.mozMatchesSelector ||
    Element.prototype.msMatchesSelector || 
    Element.prototype.oMatchesSelector || 
    Element.prototype.webkitMatchesSelector ||
    function(s) {
        var matches = (this.document || this.ownerDocument).querySelectorAll(s),
            i = matches.length;

        while (--i >= 0 && matches.item(i) !== this) {}
        return i > -1; 
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Esta versão da resposta funciona com o elemento criado posteriormente. Veja se o comportamento está mais próximo do que precisa.

Note que no on do jQuery, o evento vai subindo desde o alvo clicado até o elemento onde foi anexado o evento (no exemplo, document), e tentei simular isso aqui também, ali onde anexei um evento para quando clicar em alguma parte no div pai dos links testa essa parte.

Finalmente, juntando as ideias dos colegas e entendendo melhor a pergunta, podemos ter algo assim:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Sem necessidade para jQuery</title>

<style>
a {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #005;
  width: 10px;
}

a:hover {
  color: #aaf;
  cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div class='links'>
  <a class="qq-coisa">A</a>
  <a class="test foo">B</a>
  <a class="foo">C</a>
  <a class="test">D</a>
</div>

</body>

<script>
Node.prototype.meuOn = function(tipo, seletor, callback) {
  this.addEventListener(tipo, function(evento) {
    var el = evento.target;
    do {
      if (el.matches(seletor)) {
        callback(evento);
        break;
      }
    } while ((el = el.parentNode) != this);
  });
}

document.meuOn('click', 'a.qq-coisa', function(evento) { console.log('qualquer coisa'); console.log(evento); });
document.meuOn('click', 'a.foo', function() { console.log('foo'); });
document.meuOn('click', 'a.test:not(.foo)', function() { console.log('meuOn correto'); });
document.meuOn('click', 'div.links', function() { console.log('clicou no div?'); });

var newLink = document.createElement('a');
newLink.classList.add('qq-coisa');
newLink.innerHTML = 'E?';
document.body.appendChild(newLink);


</script>

</html>
```

**Links úteis**

- [Vanilla JS equivalents of jQuery methods](https://gist.github.com/joyrexus/7307312)
- [Understanding Event Delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Comment: forEach eu sei usar, esse nem de longe é o comportamento do `$.on`, não se baseie pelas respostas se baseie pela pergunta, entenda ela, nem você e nem o Renan entenderam o comportamento esperado do script. Leia na "pergunta" em especial a parte que eu escrevi isto: `mesmo que você crie o elemento depois do evento já estar adicionado`

Comment: com suas últimas edições e o comentário entendi melhor o comportamento, vou editar minha resposta.

Comment: Muito obrigado, fico aguardando ;)

Comment: demorei, mas aí está

Comment: Muitíssimo obrigado! Só uma dica, troque `Node` por `Element`, `Node` representa `#text` também o que pode ser um problema ;)

Comment: Se trocar Node por Element, não poderá anexar os eventos em document como no exemplo. Todo objeto document implementa a interface Document (e consequentemente as interfaces Node e EventTarget). (https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document)

Comment: Falha minha, é verdade.