# Exibir o teclado numérico quando um input receber foco na versão mobile

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, formulário, mobile, input

Estou desenvolvendo uma interface web com `HTML5`, `CSS3` e o framework `Bootstrap 3`, e usando o `type="number"` na tag `<input>` nos smartphones o teclado nativo do `Android` abre em modo numérico.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="number" name="cepusuario" id="cepusuario" class="form-control" placeholder="_____-___" />
</div>
```

Porém o campo exibe o recurso de acréscimo e decréscimo de valor decimal, e a finalidade do campo não é número inteiro e sim para CEP. Alterando para  `type="text"` do `<input>`, o teclado que se abre é o "qwerty"`type="text"`, e não é o resultado esperado.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" name="cepusuario" id="cepusuario" class="form-control" placeholder="_____-___" />
</div>
```

De que modo adapto o campo `type="text"` para que nos smartphones o teclado numérico nativo seja exibido ao invés do "qwerty".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estou bem certo que **não é possível customizar os teclados** em iOS e Android via **páginas web** e **se existir** algo provavelmente **não é *cross-platform***.

A minha sugestão para contornar o problema é usar `type="tel"` (porque `type="number"` não permite usar valores diferentes de números dentro do `value=""`) com uma máscara simples para CEP, assim o `keyup`+`regex` já removeria o que não é numero e o que não é hífen

Eu criei um exemplo bem simples:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    console.log('DOM carregou');
    
    var cepusuario = document.getElementById('cepusuario');
    
    if (!cepusuario) return;
    
    var mascaraCEPTimeout;
    
    cepusuario.addEventListener('input', function () {
        if (mascaraCEPTimeout) clearTimeout(mascaraCEPTimeout);
        
        mascaraCEPTimeout = setTimeout(mascaraCEP, 200);
    });
    
    function mascaraCEP()
    {
         var cep = cepusuario.value.replace(/\D+/, ''); //Remove tudo que não for numero

         cep = cep.replace(/^(\d{5})(\d{1,3}).*$/, '$1-$2');      
         cepusuario.value = cep;
    }
});
```

```html
<input type="tel" name="cepusuario" id="cepusuario" class="form-control" placeholder="_____-___" />
```

### Explicações sobre as regex

A regex `/\D+/` remove qualquer coisa que não for numero, deixando então somente o que é numero.

A regex `/^(\d{5})(\d{1,3}).*$/` pega no primeiro grupo `(\d{5})` os primeiros 5 numeros e adiciona ao replace para `$1-`

O segundo grupo `(\d{1,3})` pega de um a três numeros após o quinto numero do `value` e aplica ao `$2` que vem depois do hífen.

O `.*$` remove qualquer numero que sobrou (ou foi digitado a mais), neste caso para facilitar seria interessante também usar `maxlength=""` no `<input>`, porque evitaria a pessoa digitar a mais, deve-se usar `maxlength="9"`, porque apesar do CEP ter 8 números o hífen tem que ser contado também.

Ficando algo como:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    console.log('DOM carregou');
    
    var cepusuario = document.getElementById('cepusuario');
    
    if (!cepusuario) return;
    
    var mascaraCEPTimeout;
    
    cepusuario.addEventListener('input', function () {
        if (mascaraCEPTimeout) clearTimeout(mascaraCEPTimeout);
        
        mascaraCEPTimeout = setTimeout(mascaraCEP, 200);
    });
    
    function mascaraCEP()
    {
         var cep = cepusuario.value.replace(/\D+/, ''); //Remove tudo que não for numero

         cep = cep.replace(/^(\d{5})(\d{1,3}).*$/, '$1-$2');      
         cepusuario.value = cep;
    }
});
```

```html
<input type="tel" name="cepusuario" id="cepusuario" class="form-control" placeholder="_____-___" maxlength="9" />
```

Comment: Vou adaptar para usar em classes ao invés de Id's para minha necessidade, funcionou perfeito, obrigado!

Comment: @EliseuB. por nada, sim é possivel adaptar com classes usando um for, ou então para simplificar poderia usar delegação de eventos, aplicando keyup (para iOS, input evento em delegação não funciona no iOS -.-), veja como aplicar a delegação: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/210753/3635 ... se precisar de um "polyfill" para rodar em navegadores e celulares mais antigos veja a minha resposta (que é um adendo a resposta do Sérgio): https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/211420/3635 (delegação ajuda a evitar que tenha que adicionar os eventos "manualmente" e nem precisará do `DOMContentLoaded` ou `onload`)