# Otimizar adicionar eventos a diversos elementos em JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Tenho a seguinte duvida: Como otimizar o script abaixo? No total são 14 *clicks* e cada um altera um determinado ID. Não quero usar jQuery.

Script que adiciona os *listeners* de evento:

```
document.getElementById("btn-1").addEventListener("click", function () {
  myFunction(1);
});
document.getElementById("btn-2").addEventListener("click", function () {
  myFunction(2);
});
document.getElementById("btn-3").addEventListener("click", function () {
  myFunction(3);
});
document.getElementById("btn-4").addEventListener("click", function () {
  myFunction(4);
});
```

Script que altera os estilos conforme o valor passado:

```
function myFunction(a) {
  if (a === 1) {
    document.getElementById("cid-1").style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById("area-1").style.fill = '#dfdca3';
  } else if (a === 2) {
    document.getElementById("cid-2").style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById("area-2").style.fill = '#ed694b';
  } else if (a === 3) {
    document.getElementById("cid-3").style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById("area-3").style.fill = '#5fa7c8';
  } else if (a === 4) {
    document.getElementById("cid-4").style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById("area-4").style.fill = '#cce2e8';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Em relação aos *listeners* de evento, você pode criar um *array* com números e obter os IDs através de um `forEach`. Algo assim:

```js
[1, 2, 3, 4].forEach((num) => {
  document.getElementById(`btn-${num}`).addEventListener('click', () => {
    myFunction(num);
  });
});
```

Com isso você reduz N chamadas explícitas para N chamadas implícitas, já que usou um *array* com `forEach` para remover código desnecessário.

---

Agora você pode modificar a função `myFunction` para evitar o extenso número de condições. Primeiramente, você pode obter os elementos `#cid-*` e `#area-*` de forma dinâmica através do parâmetro `num` que é recebido. Também pode usar um objeto para criar um tipo de mapa, associando cada número a uma cor hexadecimal específica. Algo assim:

```js
function myFunction(num) {
  const cidEl = document.getElementById(`cid-${num}`);
  const areaEl = document.getElementById(`area-${num}`);

  const map = {
    1: '#dfdca3',
    2: '#ed694b',
    3: '#5fa7c8',
    4: '#cce2e8'
  };

  // Obtemos o valor hexadecimal:
  const hexCode = map[num];

  // Verificação para saber se temos um item correspondente no mapa,
  // e os elementos foram encontrados. Caso não, simplesmente não fará nada.
  if (!cidEl || !areaEl || !hexCode) {
    return; // Você pode tratar de forma diferente, se desejar.
  }

  cidEl.style.display = 'block';
  areaEl.style.fill = hexCode;
}
```

#### Para um maior aprofundamento

- [`Array.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach);
- [Trabalhando com objetos em JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Trabalhando_com_Objetos).

Comment: Entendi!! Vou dar uma estuda no seu código pra aprender. Mas pelo que vi ele atende e muito bem. Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

Usando "variáveis", exemplo:

```
function myFunction(a) {
    var cid, color;

    if (a === 1) {
      cid = a;
      color = '#dfdca3';
    } else if (a === 2) {
      cid = a;
      color = '#ed694b';
    } else if (a === 3) {
      cid = a;
      color = '#5fa7c8';
    } else if (a === 4) {
      cid = a;
      color = '#cce2e8';
    }

    if (cid) {
       document.getElementById("cid-" + cid).style.display = 'block';
       document.getElementById("area-" + cid).style.fill = '#cce2e8';
    }
}
```

Não necessariamente otimiza, mas diminui o código.

### Delegando eventos

No entanto adicionar isto a 14 botões é que deve ser o seu real problema, então neste caso você poderia optar pela [delegação de eventos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/210753/3635), ficaria algo como:

```
var ids = [1, 2, 3, 4]; //Botões por numeros apenas

//Unico evento necessário aplicado ao document
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

    //Checa se o click no document veio de um dos botões
    var correto = e.target.matches('#btn-' + ids.join(', #btn-'));

    //Se veio de um dos botões pega o ID remove a parte btn- e passa para a função o valor
    if (correto) {
        myFunction(parseInt(e.target.id.replace(/^btn-/, '')));
    }
});
```

A grande vantagem disto sobre usar aplicar diretamente aos elementos é que não precisa usar `window.onload` ou `DOMContentLoaded` e nem checar se o elemento existe, porque ele já contorna tudo isto, inclusive se remover o elemento nem precisará usar o `removeEventListener`.

Comment: Massa! já da uma "enxugada" nos códigos. Vou dar um estudada nessa parada de delegar eventos. Valew msm!!

Comment: @DMiaguy A grande vantagem disto sobre usar aplicar diretamente aos elementos é que não precisa usar window.onload ou DOMContentLoaded e nem checar se o elemento existe, porque ele já contorna tudo isto, inclusive se remover o elemento nem precisará usar o removeEventListener.

Answer (score 0):

Em vez de usar id's em sequência, eu sugeriria usar `class`. Assim, você só vai precisar colocar a mesma `class` em cada botão e outra `class` em cada elemento que queira mostrar, e buscar dentro desse elemento o elemento quer quer aplicar o `fill`. Basta usar o `querySelectorAll()`.

Aqui a função do `forEach` retorna duas variáveis (`el` e `a`), onde a primeira é o próprio elemento e a segunda o índice (o primeiro elemento tem índice `0`, o segundo `1` e assim por diante), e você passa o índice do botão clicado como parâmetro para a outra função `myFunction()`:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".btns").forEach(function(el,a){
   el.addEventListener("click", function () {
      myFunction(a);
   });
});
```

Os botões teriam a classe `.btns` (não precisa de id's):

```
<button class="btns">btn-1</button>
<button class="btns">btn-2</button>
<button class="btns">btn-3</button>
<button class="btns">btn-4</button>
```

Como cada índice de um botão irá se relacionar com cada elemento a ser mostrado (`style.display = 'block'`), é só usar o `querySelectorAll(classe)[índice]` para mostrar o elemento e buscar dentro dele o elemento que receberá o fill.

No exemplo abaixo, cada `svg` possui a mesma classe `.cid`. O primeiro tem índice `0`, o segundo `1` e assim por diante, da mesma forma que tem os botões. Como a função `myFunction(a)` irá receber o índice do botão clicado, basta buscar o mesmo `svg` que possua o mesmo índice dentro da classe `.cid`. Ao meu ver é uma vantagem o uso de `class` porque torna o código um pouco mais flexível e enxuto:

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".btns").forEach(function(el,a){
   el.addEventListener("click", function () {
      myFunction(a);
   });
});

function myFunction(a) {

   const cores = {
      0: 'dfdca3',
      1: 'ed694b',
      2: '5fa7c8',
      3: 'cce2e8'
   }

   let svg = document.querySelectorAll(".cid")[a];

   svg.style.display = 'block';
   svg.querySelector("circle").style.fill = '#'+cores[a];
}
```

```css
svg{
   display: none;
}
```

```html
<button class="btns">btn-1</button>
<button class="btns">btn-2</button>
<button class="btns">btn-3</button>
<button class="btns">btn-4</button>
<svg class="cid" width="100" height="100">
   <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" />
</svg>
<svg class="cid" width="100" height="100">
   <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" />
</svg>
<svg class="cid" width="100" height="100">
   <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" />
</svg>
<svg class="cid" width="100" height="100">
   <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" />
</svg>
```

Comment: opa! Interessante não ter que ficar colocando id em tudo e sim puxar pela classe, vou estudar aqui para ver como fica. Muito obrigado!