# Como enviar Tokens do servidor para o cliente?

Tags: http, token, http-headers

Estou criando uma API, nela uso autenticação via Token (JWT), quero que esse token tenha validade de, por exemplo, 10 minutos, e, a cada requisição, retorne um Token novo, assim o usuário terá acesso enquanto estiver ativo, se ficar desconectado por muito tempo (mais de 10 min), terá que se reautenticar

O cliente deve criar duas requisições, uma pedindo o recurso principal (uma busca de usuários, por exemplo) e outra para um novo token? Ou é melhor que o backend sempre retorne, além da busca de usuários, um novo token?

No caso da segunda opção, como enviar esse token? Passar como parte do corpo? Existe algum cabeçalho HTTP específico para isso? Há algum problema em passar o token via Cookie?

Vi o uso de um cabeçalho `Token` e do `Authorization` mas não encontrei nada oficial, apenas em blogs. Sei que o segundo é usado para passar o token do cliente para o servidor, vice-versa também?

O cabeçalho `Token` não aparece na MDN, nem nos não oficiais da Wikipédia  (en)

O cabeçalho `Authorization` só aparece para requisições, ou seja, do cliente para o servidor

Comment: Primeiro, recomendo a leitura: [O que é e para que serve JWT?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/155013/o-que-%C3%A9-e-para-que-serve-jwt/155045). Resumindo: O cliente deve fazer uma requisição do tipo `post` requisitando o `token`(composto por `cabelho.corpo.assinatura`), a resposta dessa requisição deve ser adicionado um hearder `Baerer` com o token Jwt. Você deve ter algum mecanismo no back-end para validar se o token é válido nas próximas requets

Comment: Se for em C#: [ASP.NET Core 2.0: autenticação em APIs utilizando JWT (JSON Web Tokens)](https://medium.com/@renato.groffe/asp-net-core-2-0-autentica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-em-apis-utilizando-jwt-json-web-tokens-4b1871efd)

Comment: @Marconi a dúvida não é como funciona o JWT ou como implementa-lo, a dúvida é qual a forma mais recomendada de enviar ele do servidor para o cliente, ou seja, a criação e validação já está pronta e funcionando. Nenhum dos links fala sobre isso, apenas como implementar e como enviar do cliente para o servidor (o que já sei)

Comment: Mano segue um tutorial detalhado de como fazer ,
parte 1
https://imasters.com.br/front-end/implementando-autenticacao-jwt-utilizando-react parte 2
https://imasters.com.br/back-end/implementando-autenticacao-jwt-o-back-end

Comment: Olá amigo, acredito que o que você está procurando seja algo relacionado a _refresh tokens_ e _sliding-sessions_ (sessões que expiram em determinado tempo de **inatividade**), de uma olhada nesse [artigo](https://auth0.com/blog/refresh-tokens-what-are-they-and-when-to-use-them/), ele fala sobre isso.

Answer (score 9):

O ideal é ter um recurso que faça a autenticação do cliente e retone um token para ele.

Quanto ao cabeçalho `Token` eu não o conheço e também não achei referências a eles, muito provavelmente é um cabeçalho personalizado, normalmente vejo este termo associado ao esquema do token como se fosse um esquema mais genérico, outros termos para o esquema são `Bearer` e `Basic` só que estes dois especificam o tipo do token.

Quanto ao cabeçalho `Authorization` ele é usado apenas para passar o token do cliente para o servidor.

Agora, por que é melhor ter um recurso que faça uma autenticação do cliete e retorne um token do que a propria API entregar um token para o cliente quando o token dele expirar? Vejamos em dois cenários:

**No primeiro cenário** um *cliente A* se autentica e recebe um *token X*. Este *token X* é capturado por um *cliente B* que o utiliza para fazer requisições. Após 10 minutos o token espira. Quando o *Cliente A* fizer uma requisição para o servidor irá receber um novo token (o *Token Y*) e, da mesma forma, quando o *Cliente B* fizer uma requisição também receberá um novo token para ele (o *Token Z*). **Logo**, neste cenário, o *Cliente B* mesmo sem ter feito a autenticação corretamente (já que ele "roubou" o token do *Cliente A*) consegue um token válido para requisições para a API fornecido pela própria API.

**No segundo cenário** um *cliente A* se autentica e recebe um *token X*. Este *token X* é capturado por um *cliente B* que o utiliza para fazer requisições. Após 10 minutos o token espira. Quando o *Cliente A* fizer uma requisição para o servidor irá retornar com uma mensagem de erro e requisitar que o cliente se autentique novamete para receber um novo token (o *Token Y*) e, da mesma forma, o *Cliente B* também receberá uma mensagem requisitando que se autentique novamenete. **Logo**, neste cenário, o *Cliente B* inicialmente consegue fazer requisições para a API utilzando o token capturado do *Cliente A* porém quando este token expirar ele perderá o acesso a API tendo que capturar um novo token.

**Considerações Finais:**

- O limite de 10 minutos para um token é justamente utilizado para obrigar o cliente a se re-autenticar sempre que o token expirar tentando garantir que o cliente ainda tem acesso a API e que um cliente não autoriazado tenha acesso a API capturando tokens de clientes autorizados.
- O token de acesso do cliente é, quase sempre, enviado no corpo da resposta a requisição de autenticação. Isto pode parecer inseguro porém se estiver trabalhando sobre `HTTPS` esta informação estará cifrada.

Comment: O problema de um cliente roubar o token do outro pode ser resolvido guardando no banco de dados qual o próximo token válido, isso também impede que dois usuários usem a mesma conta ao mesmo tempo. Além disso, se ele conseguiu roubar uma vez o token, provavelmente ele poderá fazer de novo. Além disso pedir que o usuário se reautentifique a cada 10 min é péssimo pra UX. Além disso, para a API enviar um novo token apenas quando necessário sem uma reautentificacão do usuário seria necessário um socket, que aumentaria a complexidade do sistema desnecessariamnete, fora que se você tem ...

Comment: Uma conexão via socket você nem precisa de tokens para autenticação. O limite de 10 min é para que se a pessoa pare de usar o sistema (inatividade), ela seja desconectada. Na verdade nem seria 10 min, é pouco tempo, seria uns 30 min no mínimo