# Onde realmente devo manter o meu token JWT?

Tags: javascript, jwt, single-page-application

Em muitos tutoriais (em sua maioria de *Single Page Applications*), o método de autenticação mais comum é o [JWT token](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/155013/o-que-%C3%A9-e-para-que-serve-jwt/155045).

O problema é que a maioria deles recomendam persistir esse token no `localStorage` do navegador. Prática essa que muitos afirmam ser insegura.

Isso me faz questionar:

1. Por que armazenar o token JWT na API `localStorage` é considerado inseguro?
2. Se o `localStorage` é inseguro, qual é a melhor forma de armazenar estes tokens?
3. Quais são as alternativas para o armazenamento do JWT token?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. O localStorage do navegador (ou armazenamento de sessão) não é seguro. Qualquer dado armazenado pode estar vulnerável a scripts entre sites. Se um invasor roubar um token, ele poderá acessar e fazer solicitações à sua API.
2. Se o aplicativo tiver um servidor de backend, os tokens devem ser manipulados no lado do servidor usando o fluxo de login da aplicacao Web(
   por exemplo: em um servico no backend feito em NodeJS, a validacao do token e feita atraves de um middleware que proteje uma rota caso o token seja invalido ).
3. Alternativa: **cookies**. Você também pode usar cookies para armazenar o JWT. A maneira exata de definir um cookie depende da linguagem que você está usando.

### Um pouco mais sobre Cookies

Existem diferentes opções para controlar o tempo de vida de um cookie:

- Os cookies podem ser destruídos depois que o navegador é fechado (cookies de sessão).
- Implemente uma verificação do lado do servidor (geralmente feita por você pela estrutura da linguagem Web em uso) e você poderá implementar a expiração ou a expiração da janela (navegador ao ser fechado).
- Os cookies podem ser persistentes (não destruídos após o navegador ser fechado) com uma data de expiração.

Os cookies podem ser lidos pelo código do lado do servidor e do JavaScript ou apenas pelo lado do servidor se o sinalizador `httpOnly` estiver definido.

Você pode definir o sinalizador `secure = true` para que os cookies só possam ser definidos em uma conexão criptografada.

---

### ATENÇÃO

**Desvantagens dos cookies:**

O tamanho máximo de um cookie é de apenas 4kb, o que pode ser problemático se você tiver muitas declarações anexadas ao token.

Os cookies podem ser vulneráveis a ataques de falsificação de solicitações entre sites (CSRF ou XSRF). O uso da proteção CSRF de uma estrutura de aplicacao Web torna os cookies uma opção segura para armazenar um JWT.

O CSRF também pode ser parcialmente impedido, verificando o cabeçalho `HTTP Referer` e `Origin`. Você também pode definir o sinalizador de cookie restrito `SameSite = Strict`([saiba mais](https://www.netsparker.com/blog/web-security/same-site-cookie-attribute-prevent-cross-site-request-forgery/)), onde com esta politica, os cookies nao podem ser enviados para sites de terceiros, o que ajuda a evitar ataques de CSRF.

Pode ser difícil de implementar se o aplicativo exigir acesso entre domínios. Os cookies têm propriedades adicionais (Domínio / Caminho) que podem ser modificadas para permitir que você especifique onde o cookie pode ser enviado.

---

### Referências

- [Cookies vs. Tokens: The Definitive Guide](https://dzone.com/articles/cookies-vs-tokens-the-definitive-guide)
- [Sobre ataques **CSRF**](https://www.infosec.com.br/cross-site-request-forgery/).
- [Client-side Authentication the Right Way (Cookies vs. Local Storage)](https://www.taniarascia.com/full-stack-cookies-localstorage-react-express/)
  . Este artigo, mostra as diferencas entra usar Cookies e o LocalStorage para salvar dados sensíveis e como armazenar JWTs em uma aplicação NodeJS.

Answer (score -1):

Manter o JWT no localstorage é comum, é bom apenas ficar atento ao conteúdo que é salvo no token. Normalmente salvamos o objeto do cliente logado, porém é bom ficar atento com os dados sensíveis do mesmo, eles não precisam estar presentes no JWT, também validar sempre no lado do servidor pra identificar que aquele JWT ainda é valido.

Answer (score -3):

Normalmente é armazenado no localstorage mesmo. É inseguro apenas se alguma pessoa ver o token na sua maquina na hora que voce logar na aplicação.