# Acessar vários sistemas com uma única credencial, tipo o Google

Tags: laravel, login, microsserviços, laravel-8

Então, estou criando pequenos sistemas (Produtos) no láravel 8 e estou com uma duvida para fazer o acesso (Login) nesses sistemas. Seria possível fazer uma única autenticação e o cliente poder acessar todos os produtos tipo o Google que você loga uma única vez e pode acessar o Gmail, Google Drive, Google Docs e etc.

Hoje nos sistemas normais eu uso a autenticação padrão do laravel, como mostro abaixo.

```
public function index()
{
    return view('Admin.auth.login');
}

/**
 * Handle an authentication attempt.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */

public function authenticate(Request $request)
{
    $credentials = $request->validate([
        'email' => ['required', 'email'],
        'password' => ['required'],
    ]);

    $remember = $request->remember?true:false;

    if (Auth::guard('user')->attempt($credentials, $remember)) {
        // $request->session()->regenerate();

        return redirect()->intended('painel');
    }

    return back()->withErrors([
        'email' => 'As credenciais fornecidas não correspondem aos nossos registros.',
    ]);
}

/**
 * Log the user out of the application.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function logout(Request $request)
{
    Auth::guard('user')->logout();

    // $request->session()->invalidate();
    // $request->session()->regenerateToken();

    return redirect('/painel');
}
```

Desde já agradeço pela atenção de todos.

Comment: Quando você diz que está criando pequenos sistemas/produtos, significa que são projetos separados, com banco de dados diferentes e sem comunicação direta (um projeto não tem classes funções de outros projetos)?

Comment: Exatamente isso, serão pequenos produtos que se tiver comunicação será via API e todos eles serão acessados de uma única plataforma, é onde o cliente irá fazer o login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Há 2 formas:

1. Criar uma aplicação que será usada pra gerenciar os usuários e forneça um meio para outros serviços a acessarem afim de validar o usuário. A aplicação cliente faz o login no serviços de usuários, que armazena um token no banco e o retorna pro cliente, esse token é enviado para todos os serviços que precisem de autenticação e esses serviços consultam o serviço de usuários pra verificar se o token é válido e qual usuário está atrelado aquele token

Apesar de funcionar, essa forma requer que o serviço de autenticação seja chamado muitas vezes pelos demais serviços, por isso, é recomendado o segundo meio...

2. Criar um serviço separado para genrenciar os usuários também, porém, o token gerado por ele deve ser um [JWT (JSON Web Token)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/155013/91006), como ele tem uma parte criptografada e apenas você tem a chave secreta (idependente do algoritimo que for utilizar), pode verificar se aquela assinatura está correta, se sim, pode confiar nos dados do token. No payload você também pode enviar algumas informções úteis do usuário, como id, nível de permissão (role), email ou telefone, com esses dados, seus outros serviços provavelmente não precisaram acessar o serviço de usuários recorrentemente, mas em alguns casos pode ser necessaŕio obter todos os dados. Note que não é necessário armazenar esse token em nenhum banco de dados do lado do servidor, apenas o cliente armazena essa informação (em LocalStorage, por exemplo)

Pra implementar o primeiro meio, basta criar os endpoints necessários da forma que preferir, pro segundo, também precisará usar uma [biblioteca](https://jwt.io/libraries) pra facilitar a criação e validação dos tokens e manter a(s) chave(s) de criptografia em todas as aplicações que precisarem criar ou validar o token

---

Especificamente pro Laravel, você pode utilizar o [jwt-auth](https://jwt-auth.readthedocs.io/en/develop/), tem uma explicação e exemplos [nesse tutorial em português](https://medium.com/jwt-laravel-para-autentica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-servi%C3%A7os/jwt-laravel-para-autentica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-servi%C3%A7os-86d933f5c1a2)